# Another exception was thrown: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///

Tags: flutter, networkimageview

I displayed network image using drive url link and I got this error.But after 5 sec , display image .But before display image,display error message in screen.How can I solve that?

```html
ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
  valueListenable:_pageManager.currentSongTitleNotifier,
  builder: (_, imagelink, __) {
    print(imagelink);
    return imagelink == null ?
      Container() 
      :Container(
      child:Image.network(imagelink),
    );
  }
),
```

Comment: You'll get better syntax highlighting(and therefore better answers) if you use three backticks above and below your block of code instead of posting as a javascript snippet. Check out the syntax highlighting section on this answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Is it possible to replace '///' to '//'  of the url?

Comment: @Fahmida. In my url, only // contain.

Comment: Did you try adding 'https://' to the uri